# How can I access the last inserted row ID within a SQL script?

Tags: sqlite, relational

I'm using SQLite, and I have a table for properties, and a table for sub-properties.  Each sub-property points to its parent using the fkPropertyId column.  Right now, to create the initial database, I've got a script that looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO property VALUES(1,.....);
INSERT INTO property VALUES(2,.....);
INSERT INTO property VALUES(3,.....);
   INSERT INTO subproperty VALUES(1,.....,3);
   INSERT INTO subproperty VALUES(2,.....,3);
   INSERT INTO subproperty VALUES(3,.....,3);
INSERT INTO property VALUES(4,.....);
```

Now, I want to get rid of the hard-coded rowId, so it would be something like:

```
INSERT INTO property VALUES(NULL,.....);
INSERT INTO property VALUES(NULL,.....);
INSERT INTO property VALUES(NULL,.....);
   INSERT INTO subproperty VALUES(NULL,.....,X);
   INSERT INTO subproperty VALUES(NULL,.....,X);
   INSERT INTO subproperty VALUES(NULL,.....,X);
INSERT INTO property VALUES(NULL,.....);
```

Where x refers to the last inserted rowId in the property table.  Right now, that's

```
(SELECT MAX(rowId) FROM property)
```

Is there any better (and more technically accurate) way to write this script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the solution I came up with used the `last_insert_rowid` function from Ben S:

```
INSERT INTO property VALUES(NULL,.....);
INSERT INTO property VALUES(NULL,.....);

   INSERT INTO subproperty VALUES(1,.....,-1);
   INSERT INTO subproperty VALUES(2,.....,-1);
   INSERT INTO subproperty VALUES(3,.....,-1);
INSERT INTO property VALUES(NULL,.....);
UPDATE subproperty SET fkPropertyId = (SELECT last_insert_rowid()) WHERE fkPropertyId=-1;

INSERT INTO property VALUES(NULL,.....);
```

Not sure if that's the best approach, but it works for me, and it doesn't use any extra tables for temporary data storage.

Answer (score 30):

Use the [`last_insert_rowid`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) function:

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid();
```

Comment: How do I keep that value for three consecutive inserts?

Comment: Just insert the property row first, then the subproperty. If you need to remember the property ID for more than one insert, assign it to a variable before doing the subproperty inserts.

Comment: my problem is that this is a sqlite script and as far as I know, sqlite doesn't support user variables in scripts