# How to insert a automatically generated rowid to another table in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, atomic, rowid

If I like to insert something into a table 'things' and a first reference to it in another table 'thing_tags', how can I make sure this is atomically done?

Using two queries, I would do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO things(thing) VALUES("a thing");
INSERT INTO thing_tags(thing_id,tag) VALUES(SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM things), "a default tag");
```

However, this makes to queries, I am not sure if some other query could go inbetween, and it looks useless complicated.
Is there a simple and clean way to insert the tag referencing the new thing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access the last inserted row ID within a SQL script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822135/how-can-i-access-the-last-inserted-row-id-within-a-sql-script)

Comment: This should not be done from inside SQL. What language are you using to access SQLite?